# HashMap One key with multiple values without knowing what values you get

Tags: java, object, dictionary, hashmap

Okay I looked up some threads about my problem but in every solution they use (atleast in the most) something like:

```
Map<Key, ArrayList<Value>> myMap = new HashMap...;
//this Map is an attribute of my first Object so the Key is the second 
  Object and my ArrayList is the relation
```

Input like: `String1 (nr=2) relation String2`
So in my case I will be getting some Names and Numbers to create an Object (already done). The relation String in between is telling me in which relation those Objects should be but there could also be the `Object of String1` being in relation with `String2 Object` but also with another `String3 Object`. So my problem right now is that if I read my input in from my file it's going to overwrite the first relation.

But if I use the method with the ArrayList I must know which relation exists. Because in my input file there will be something like:

```
String1 relation String2
String3 relation String5
String1 relation String4
```

so I also can't just add the relation and the second Object in the Map up.

Hope you understood my question. (not a native speaker)

Thanks in advance

Comment: sounds like you might need a Map<String, String> to keep track of relations. ie a map of string key to string value

Comment: It sounds like you want a `Map<String, List<RelationAndValue>>` where `RelationAndValue` is a class you create to hold both the relation and the value.

Comment: You can also try Map<String, Map<String,String>>. Where the first string is STRING1 and second one is RELATION and third one STRING2. If you have more strings with same relation than Map<String, Map<String,List<String>>>.

Answer (score 0):

Check if key is already in your map and if it is, just add relation to this key:

```
if map.containsKey(key)
{
   map.get(key).add(relation);
} else
{
   List<Object> rel = new ArrayList<Object>();
   rel.add(relation);
   map.put(key, rel);
}
```

**UPDATE:** for printing, use:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<Object> values = entry.getValue();
            for (Object value : values)
            {
                System.out.println(key + "=" + value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Okay. I tested this method and still I get sadly not all relations.. It will still only print out the latest relation added. Even if I iterate over the List containing all relations it doesn't work.. any ideas? edit: even checked now with printing the List Strings themselves out on the terminal that there is still only one saved

Comment: @NhatNienne  Added printing method.

Comment: thanks but my problem with your method is still that the first method(not the printing method) should theoretically work but it doesn't it still doesnt add all relations in the list. I don't know why but it overwrites them too

Comment: any way to give it to you in private?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71342/discussion-between-texhik-and-nhatnienne).

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing stopping you then I would look into using a multi-map implementation which has already been written. You need something like this

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

however if for some reason you can't just import one then the above method is good!